# Php code editor

Tags: php, ide

I used to code in Notepad for HTML.

Since I'm learning php now so i think it is worth it now to grab a IDE which will halve the effort required.

So, I need a syntax highlighting, lightweight PHP code editor.

Can anyone help me finding one?

Comment: This isn't "find me an IDE". Also look at the millions of duplicates on the Right-Hand Side of your screen, where it says "Related". FYI these were also displayed whilst you typed out your question.

Comment: Thank you Tomalak :). I'll be careful about this fact further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short list to get you started

- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (Windows)
- [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) (Windows, Mac, Linux)
- [Gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) (Windows, Mac, Linux)

Comment: Hey ! thanks for the suggestions. can u help me a little more ?? what's the difference between "komodo IDE" and "komodo Edit" ???

Comment: @Anas The IDE is a full IDE with debugging tools, database mangement, etc, while the Edit version is just a fancy text editor. See http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit/compare-with-komodo-ide  (disclaimer: I've never used either, but they've been recommended to me by several people)

Answer (score 5):

Notepad++ :)

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Checkout the plugins too :)

Answer (score 0):

I think best is - Netbeans 7. Very good highlight, autoformating and useful debug. http://netbeans.org/

Comment: true it's nowhere close to lightweight ... but the best when developing with framework environment.

Comment: well i have netbeans 7. But it's a little too much compared to requirement. I want real light weight ... i mean real !!  ;)